# MySQL and PHP query date = $date problems

Tags: php, mysql, date, where-clause

I'm having a simple problem with a query comparing a date in a table to a date input from a user. (give me a list of all people in the table with birthdate "MM/DD/YYYY").

When entering a new person into a db I want to verify that that person is not already in the db. So using "firstname" "lastname" and "date of birth" the table is queried and if there is a match, a window pops up and says "are you sure you want to do this - looks like the person is already entered".

There is NO PROBLEM with "firstname" "lastname" (I've got that working nicely) so now I want to add "date of birth" to the query. As a start, I removed "firstname" and "lastname" and am only using "date of birth".

As a "proof of concept" the following MySQL query works fine on the MySQL Workbench:

```
SET @testdate = "1934-06-06";
SELECT localid, firstname, lastname, dob FROM administrative WHERE dob = @testdate;
```

The "dob" column in the table is a "date" format not "datetime".

So I now switch over to php and write this as a test:

```
$frontenddob = "06/06/1934";
$dob = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($frontenddob));

echo "--$frontenddob--<br>"; //gives 06/06/1934
echo "--$dob--<br><br>";     //gives --1934-06-06-- ("--" added to "see" extra spaces)
echo "$dob"; echo "<br>";    //gives 1934-06-06

$host = "xx";
$user = "xx";
$password = "xx";
$dbname = "xx";

$cxn = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$dbname);
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {echo "No connection" . mysqli_connect_error();}

$query = " SELECT * FROM administrative WHERE dob = $dob ORDER BY lastname ASC  ";
```

The user types in a date string in the format mm/dd/yyyy.

It is converted to date format by the date("Y-m-d", strtotime($frontenddob));.

The "echos" show that the conversion is correct - the "echo $dob" gives me 1934-06-06.

The query works fine with <=, >=, <, > and I've tried everything else =, ==, ===, >=$date AND <=$date, and a raft of others - all unsuccessful.

1. The format in the table for dob (date of birth) is "date" not "datetime".
2. The user input string date format is converted to MySQL date format YYYY-MM-DD.
3. The query works with <, >, <=, >=.

Where am I going wrong?

I thank you in advance.

Comment: you never mention if it is not giving record or giving error, but as answer by @nil'z you miss single quote around $dob.

Comment: Use `var_dump` to debug variables etc. instead of `echo "--$dob--<br><br>";     //gives --1934-06-06-- ("--" added to "see" extra spaces)`...

Comment: @Sumit Gupta - Thanks for your answer! I convert the array to json and echo the json - all I got was "[]". Problem is solved by adding single quotes as noted by you and suggested by Nil'z. Thanks again!

Comment: I'll play around with "var_dump" today - never used it. Being a noob, I often don't trust myself and like to "see" a string to make sure I haven't screwed something up. Thanks for your response!

Comment: @TimSPQR print_r is nice function like var_dump, and both are good at seeing what variable hold.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
$query = " SELECT * FROM administrative WHERE dob = '$dob' ORDER BY lastname ASC  ";
                                                    ^    ^
```

Note the single quote around the `$dob`.

Comment: Yes, Yes and Yes!!! Thanks very much!!! It works perfectly now. But I guess I'll have to spend some time looking at single quote requirements. I have quite a few queries with php variables $xxxx that work fine without any quotes. The only single quotes I put around the comparison variable are LIKE '%xx%'. Obviously I need to study this a bit more. What is sad is that I put double quotes around it before I posted this, and it didn't work either. So, I thank you VERY VERY much for your answer and insight.

Comment: Happie to help buddy :D

Comment: If this `$dob` come from user_input (javascript, html, asp..), you SHOULD really think about sanitizing the variable before putting it in your select!

Answer (score 0):

I've been playing a bit with the concept of strtotime vs explode and learned in another thread that strtotime is good up until 12/13/1901. So to help other noobs such as myself, based on Alexandr's suggestions, I wrote a few lines that demonstrate the differences between the two. It's interesting to put in 1901-12-13 and 1901-12-14 I the first line of the php code. Thanks again to everyone!

```
<?php $dob = "1901-12-14"; ?>
<html>
<head>
<style>

.inputdiv {
    width:200px;
    margin:100px auto 10px auto;
    background-color:#CCC2FC;
    text-align:center;
    border:1px solid transparent;}

.spacer{
    width:199px;
    margin:20px auto 20px auto;}    

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="inputdiv">
  <div class="spacer"><?php echo "Raw dob: ".$dob ?></div>
  <div class="spacer"><?php echo "Strtotime dob: ".date("m-d-Y", strtotime($dob)) ?></div>
  <div class="spacer"><?php list ($y, $m, $d) = explode('-', $dob);
                        $dob = sprintf("%02d-%02d-%04d", $m, $d, $y);
                        echo "Explode dob: ".$dob ?></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

except using quotes, try to avoid strtotime in BIRTHDAY, because it generates timestamp (IT STARTS FROM YEAR 1970). try to use explode() for example

```
$frontenddob = "12/06/1934";
list ($m,$d,$y) = explode('/', $frontenddob);
$dob = sprintf("%04d-%02d-%02d", $y, $m, $d);
```

Comment: Very nice. I've seen "explode" before, but never used it. I'll play with it today. Thanks very much for your comment!

Comment: those who minuses, probably don't know timestamp starts from year 1970

Comment: `Try to avoid strtotime()` -- why? `because it generates a timestamp` -- well, that's what the function does.

Comment: lots of birthdays year is less then 1970, if you know what i mean

Comment: Very good point. Many of my birthdays in the db are before 1940 - so I'll definitely play with expolode today. Thank you all again!